# "Bounds cannot be changed while locked" on GridView update

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, radgridview

I have a List called “myResults”.  When the list contains at least one item, I’m trying to populate a GridView w/ info for the list; the GridView is called “gvMyResults”.  However, sometimes, during this update of the DataSource, I get an exception saying, “Bounds cannot be changed while locked”, and a red X is displayed across my GridView.  I added this Dispatcher wrapper around my update, but I’m still seeing the same error.  It’s difficult to troubleshoot, because it does not happen every time.  Also, this GridView is a Telerik RadGridView.

Does anyone know how to stop this “bounds cannot be changed while locked” error?

```
if (myResults.Count > 0) 
{
    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(
        DispatcherPriority.Normal, 
        (Action)delegate()
    {
        this.gvMyResults.DataSource = myResults;
    });
}
```

I've tried this as well, but am getting the same Exception:

```
_Context.Send(x =>
{
    this.gvMyResults.DataSource = myResults;
}, null);
```

Exception / Stack-Trace (as requested):

```
Type=System.InvalidOperationException
Source=Telerik.WinControls
Message=Bounds cannot be changed while locked.
StackTrace:
    at Telerik.WinControls.RadElement.SetBoundsCore(Rectangle bounds)
    at Telerik.WinControls.RadElement.set_Size(Size value)
    at Telerik.WinControls.RadElement.SetLayoutParams(PointF newOffset, SizeF newSize)
    at Telerik.WinControls.RadElement.ArrangeCore(RectangleF finalRect)
    at Telerik.WinControls.RadElement.Arrange(RectangleF finalRect)
    at Telerik.WinControls.UI.RowsContainerElement.ArrangeOverride(SizeF finalSize)
    at Telerik.WinControls.RadElement.ArrangeCore(RectangleF finalRect)
    at Telerik.WinControls.RadElement.Arrange(RectangleF finalRect)
    at Telerik.WinControls.UI.ScrollViewElement`1.ArrangeViewElement(RectangleF viewElementRect)
    at Telerik.WinControls.UI.ScrollViewElement`1.ArrangeOverride(SizeF finalSize)
    at Telerik.WinControls.RadElement.ArrangeCore(RectangleF finalRect)
    at Telerik.WinControls.RadElement.Arrange(RectangleF finalRect)
    at Telerik.WinControls.Layouts.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()
    at Telerik.WinControls.RadElement.UpdateLayout()
    at Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridVisibilityHelper.EnsureRowVisible(GridViewRowInfo rowInfo)
    at Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridTableElement.EnsureRowVisible(GridViewRowInfo rowInfo)
    at Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridTableElement.EnsureCellVisible(GridViewRowInfo rowInfo, GridViewColumn column)
    at Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridTableElement.UpdateViewCore(Object sender, DataViewChangedEventArgs args)
    at Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridTableElement.UpdateView(Object sender, DataViewChangedEventArgs args)
    at Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridTableElement.ProcessTemplateEvent(GridViewEvent eventData)
    at Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridTableElement.Telerik.WinControls.UI.IGridViewEventListener.ProcessEvent(GridViewEvent eventData)
    at Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridViewEventProcessEntity.ProcessCollection(GridViewEvent gridEvent, PriorityWeakReferenceList list, GridEventProcessMode processMode)
    at Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridViewEventProcessEntity.ProcessEvent(GridViewEvent gridEvent)
    at Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridViewSynchronizationService.NotifyListeners(GridViewEvent gridEvent)
    at Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridViewSynchronizationService.FlushEvents()
    at Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridViewSynchronizationService.DispatchEvent(GridViewEvent gridEvent)
    at Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridViewSynchronizationService.RaiseCurrentChanged(GridViewTemplate template, GridViewRowInfo row, GridViewColumn column, Boolean user)
    at Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridViewTemplate.CollectionView_CurrentChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    at Telerik.WinControls.Data.RadCollectionView`1.OnCurrentChanged(EventArgs args)
    at Telerik.WinControls.Data.RadCollectionView`1.SetCurrentPositionCore(Int32 newPosition, Boolean forceNotify, CurrentChangeReason reason)
    at Telerik.WinControls.Data.RadDataView`1.SyncCurrent(TDataItem item)
    at Telerik.WinControls.Data.RadDataView`1.RebuildData(Boolean notify)
    at Telerik.WinControls.Data.RadDataView`1.RefreshOverride()
    at Telerik.WinControls.Data.RadDataView`1.ProcessCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
    at Telerik.WinControls.Data.RadCollectionView`1.source_CollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    at Telerik.WinControls.Data.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    at Telerik.WinControls.Data.RadListSource`1.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    at Telerik.WinControls.Data.RadListSource`1.EndUpdate(Boolean notifyUpdates)
    at Telerik.WinControls.Data.RadListSource`1.Initialize()
    at Telerik.WinControls.Data.RadListSource`1.Bind(Object dataSource, String dataMember)
    at Telerik.WinControls.Data.RadListSource`1.set_DataSource(Object value)
    at Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridViewTemplate.set_DataSource(Object value)
    at Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadGridView.set_DataSource(Object value)
    at MyProject.MyWindow.<>c__DisplayClass2.<DisplayCallerInfo>b__0()
```

Comment: We've posted on Telerik's forums as well, but haven't heard anything yet - [link](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/winforms/gridview/bounds-cannot-be-changed-while-locked-on-gridview-update.aspx)

Comment: What about the stack trace?

Comment: @KingKing - I've added the Stack-Trace.  Thanks

Comment: These controls are not thread safe.Have you tried gvMyResults.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { this.gvMyResults.DataSource = myResults; }));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error indicates that the grid is not in valid state. I noticed in the code snippet that you update the datasource asynchronously and I would like to clarify that all UI controls are not thread safe controls in the whole Windows Forms UI platform. Here is an [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx) on MSDN describing how to make thread-safe Winforms UI application. This means that RadGridView is not thread safe as well and cannot be used outside the main UI thread. You should use an [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) to update the controls in cross threading scenario. For example:

```
if (gvMyResults.InvokeRequired)
{
   gvMyResults.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { this.gvMyResults.DataSource = myResults; }));
}
else
{ 
 this.gvMyResults.DataSource = myResults;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ajay.  I'll test this and award the bounty accordingly afterwards.

Comment: It appears to be working so far.  I should finish testing later today.

Comment: let me know when you finished